# Sharks with what attached to their heads

Tags: professor-layton, professor-layton-the-eternal-diva

In the movie *Professor Layton and the Eternal Diva*, all the sharks have an odd cone-shaped thing on their snouts.  It doesn't look like a natural part of the shark.  What is it?

[image: All the depicted sharks seem to have "birthday hat" on their snout. It looks like a grey cone drill with a yellow ball on the end.]

Comment: Obviously, those are the laser beams. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bh7bYNAHXxw

Comment: @Pete nah, pretty sure that's just an ill-tempered sea bass not a shark at all.

Comment: In a later scene we see wolves with something attached to their ears. It appears this is some kind of mind control device

Comment: @Valorum is right. I didn't even notice the wolves' ears.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3jjQ.jpg